# A line in a self define function not working in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I try and defined a function to process a df (like adding columns and convert all cols head to lower case) before doing the analysis. All other line works fine except the line that I tried to rearrange the columns orders.

the function looks like this

```
def cleanDf(df):    
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','_')
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
    df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str))
    df['weekday'] =  df['date1'].dt.day_name()
    
    business_hour_mask = (df['date1'].dt.hour >=9) & (df['date1'].dt.hour <=18)
    df['business_hour'] = np.where(business_hour_mask, "Yes","No")
    df['week_number'] = df.date1.dt.week
    
    df = df.reindex(['date1','week_number','weekday','business_hour','changed_by','customer','field_name','new_value','old_value','new_value.1','old_value.1','date','time','company_code','sales_organization','distribution_channel','division'], axis=1) 
    #problem line, i've tried both with and without "df = " in front of this line
    
    return df
```

my current workaround is to insert that line after i call the function then it works

```
cleanDf(df)

df = df.reindex(['date1','week_number','weekday','business_hour','changed_by','customer','field_name','new_value','old_value','new_value.1','old_value.1','date','time','company_code','sales_organization','distribution_channel','division'], axis=1)

df.head()
```

Appreciate if you can advise why the line does not inside the function, but ok when executed separately.

thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're reassigning the `df` variable inside the function, where it's just a parameter. Since you're returing `df` though, it's simple. Just write `df = cleanDf(df)` instead of just `cleanDf(df)`:

```
df = cleanDf(df)
df.head()
```

Per [@mozway's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069379/a-line-in-a-self-define-function-not-working-in-pandas/71069435?noredirect=1#comment125632720_71069435), you should also define your `cleanDf` function like so:

```
def cleanDf(df):
    df = df.copy()
    # ... do your stuff ...
    return df
```

Comment: @1cjtc Adding to this, you should probably also add `df = df.copy()` in the very beginning of the function to make it unambiguously **not** modifying the input (even if, in this particular case you will reassign to the same object)